# Installed bundler on OS X 10.8.5 but bundle -v gives command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash

I installed bundler 1.3.5 but when i give the command

```
bundle -v
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: bundle: command not found
```

I have installed `Ruby 2.0.0p247` but don't see `ruby` in the `PATH`. Don't know if that has something to do with it. Just in case it is relevant `echo $PATH` gives:

```
Users/username/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Disclosure: I am new to programming and not very savvy yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try running the command

```
rbenv rehash
```

then

```
bundle -v
```

read more about [rehash here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash)

Answer (score 0):

Your path looks fine. Executable programs (like `ruby` or `bundle`) are stored within the directories of your path.

To check if bundler is installed properly, you should see the following:

```
$ gem list | grep bundler
bundler (1.3.5)
$ ls ~/.rbenv/shims/ | grep bundle
bundle
```

Otherwise it's not installed properly. Try opening a new terminal window, restarting the computer, etc. If that doesn't work, uninstall / reinstall. Update with error messages or if none of that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PATH` contains a typo.  The first entry should begin with `/Users`, not `Users` (the leading slash is missing, causing Bash to search for this path underneath the current directory, instead of the root directory).

Answer (score -1):

to tell if ruby (or any executable) is reachable in your path, use which:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

try it with bundle

```
$which bundle
```

not found? try asking ruby if it has bundler installed

```
$gem list bundler
bundler (1.3.5)
```